# No Non Generic KeyValuePair class

Tags: c#, generics, keyvaluepair

I often use `Tuple.Create` on the `Tuple` class.  Now I'm creating a `KeyValuePair` with:

`new KeyValuePair<string, MyAnnoyingButNecessarilyVerboseClass>(myString, myObj)`

I didn't want to include the type arguments in this case because they obfuscate the code a bit IMO.  I've added the following to mimic `Tuple.Create` for `KeyValuePairs`.

```
public static class KVP
{
    public static KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> Create<TKey, TValue>(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value);
    }
}
```

So I can write

`KVP.Create(myString, myObj)`

without having to include type arguments explicitly because they are inferred from the other arguments.  This works nicely, and I don't see any downsides.  So I have a few very related questions.

1. Why did C# not include a non generic `System.KeyValuePair` class with a static create method?  ("They didn't because they didn't want to invest the effort for a feature that provides little value" is a completely acceptable and understandable answer)
2. Am I missing a function that does something similiar?
3. Are there downsides to creating a `KeyValuePair` class that I'm missing?
4. Is there a more terse way to create a generic `KeyValuePair` (besides shortening the class and function name obviously :))?

Comment: You're still going to have to provide type parameters to KVP.Create, just like with Tuple. You can't create a non-generic factory method which produces generic output.

Comment: Yes, KVP.Create requires type arguments.  But I don't have to explicitly provide them because they are inferred by the other arguments.  I updated my question to make what I mean a bit clearer.  (I think I used parameters where I meant arguments in two places)

Comment: I would remove question #1 as no one here (Except perhaps [Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert)) can answer that one without guessing and does not fit the Q&A format of this site.

Comment: Is your #1 basically "Why isn't my one-line method already implemented in the BCL" ? And is your #4 "Can my code consisting of a single method invocation be made shorter" ?!

Answer (score 1):

> Why did C# not include a non generic `System.KeyValuePair` class with
>   a static create method?  ("They didn't because they didn't want to
>   invest the effort for a feature that provides little value" is a
>   completely acceptable and understandable answer)

Question isn't a good fit for SO, doubtful it actually has an answer.

> Am I missing a function that does something similiar?

No, as of .net 4.5 there isn't one in the framework.

> Are there downsides to creating a `KeyValuePair` class that I'm missing?

No, I've created one myself.

> Is there a more terse way to create a generic `KeyValuePair` ?

No, that's pretty much as terse as you could do it in C#

Answer (score 0):

I think that KeyValuePair only exists at all because it predates Tuple by several versions of C#.  With Tuple they just figured out a better way to do things.

Comment: I think KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue> plays a slightly different, and important role compared to Tuple<T1,T2>.  It emphasizes a different relationship between its two properties and more importantly it fits nicely with IDictionary<TKey,TValue>.  Imagine writing code like mydictionary.Where(kvp => kvp.Item1 == "mykey") if dictionaries implemented an IEnumerable of tuples instead of KeyValuePairs...weird

Comment: Also, `KeyValuePair` is `struct` whereas `Tuple` is `class`. They both have their uses.

Answer (score 0):

a non generic equivalent for

```
KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>
```

is

```
System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
```